# Perspective projection view plane distance calculation confusion?

Tags: math, graphics, rendering, projection, perspectivecamera

I'm studying from a 3D computer graphics book trying to implement my own software renderer for educational purposes. Everything was going great until the book started talking about perspective projection, it got a bit confusing.

The book (Tricks of the 3D Game Programming Gurus) was talking about computing `d`: the distance from the view point to the view plane. If we look at this scanned image from the book (I hope Andre doesn't mind because I tried contacting him asking but no reply):

[image]

Well, here it's clear that the author meant 0.5 * Width besides the figure and not Width.

Then he continues to say:

```
tan(θ) = opposite/adjacent = y/x, and in this case, y is the distance and x is related to the width.
```

Looking at the figure, I can't see how this is correct because the opposite of the angle `θ/2` is `W/2` and the adjacent is `d`. So:

```
tan(θ/2) = (W/2) / d =>
d * tan(θ/2) = (W/2) =>
d = (W/2) / tan(θ/2)
```

Am I wrong? am I missing anything? did the author mean something else?

Any ideas/thoughts/explanations are appreciated.

**EDIT:** Although in the book's code it does 'work' when multiplication is used, but it's not correct. Because objects should get smaller the higher FOV value is used, that's why division is correct. But if multiplication is used the higher the FOV the bigger objects get. I think the author didn't notice this because he was using 90 degrees FOV angle most the times and `tan(90/2)=1` so it doesn't matter if we multiplied or divided.

Comment: `Q` is just theta in the diagram - the field of view angle. (edited/changed Q to the theta symbol)

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah 
Could you elaborate more on 'd cancels out'?

Comment: I'm just unsure as to which 'final equations' are you referring to. But if you think your explanation would help, yes please. Post it so I can accept it as an answer, cause I pretty much have my answer now.

Comment: OOPS apologies for my misguided comments. `d` does not actually _cancel out_ per se, but is in fact *taken to be the Z-coordinate of the point* in camera space (so the number getting stored in the "Z-buffer".

Comment: Yes d is basically the z coordinate of the view plane it seems.

Comment: no I mean the z coordinate of _the point_ you're projecting